# Kann ein Doppelpunkt den Umfang des Dativs der Präposition Zwischen widerrufen?

Tags: preposition, dative

Sind die beiden folgenden Sätze richtig? Ich bin mir nicht so sicher, ob das Verwenden des Doppelpunktes (:) im zweiten Satz den Umfang des Dativs der Präposition **Zwischen** widerruft.

1. Das Buch geht um das Treffen zwischen diesen Wissenschaftlern, dem
   Physiker Adolf R. und dem Astronomen Mujiko P.
2. Das Buch geht um das Treffen zwischen diesen Wissenschaftlern: der
   Physiker Adolf R. und der Astronom Mujiko P.

Comment: Nebenbei, falls du den Satz wo hinschreiben willst: _geht um_ kommt mir hier etwas flapsig vor. Ich würde _handelt von_ verwenden.

Comment: Nur eine Anmerkung zum Stil abseits der Frage: Das Buch *geht* nicht *um*, es *handelt von*. Es ist allgemein bekannt, dass Physiker und Astronomen Wissenschaftler sind. Wenn *das Treffen* kein allgemein bekanntes Ereignis ist, sollte es vielleicht besser *ein Treffen* heißen. Kurz: *Das Buch handelt von einem Treffen zwischen dem Physiker Adolf R. und dem Astronomen Mujiko P.*

Comment: @Olafant, dem ist nichts hinzuzufügen.

Comment: Jedoch, wenn auch vielleicht nicht übermäßig schön: In dem Buch geht es um...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aus der Art, wie Sie die Frage formuliert haben, lese ich heraus, dass Sie die Variante mit *dem Dativ und dem Komma* als Standardvariante ansehen und dass Sie nicht sicher sind, ob der Dativ noch gültig ist, wenn Sie von diesem vermeintlichen Standard abweichen und einen Doppelpunkt verwenden.

Es ist jedoch gerade umgekehrt: Die Variante mit *dem Dativ und dem Doppelpunkt* ist die Standardvariante, denn es handelt sich hier um eine ganz gewöhnliche angekündigte Aufzählung – ein Paradebeispiel für den Gebrauch des Doppelpunkts. Ein Komma ergibt hier eigentlich keinen Sinn; ich empfinde es sogar als falsch, es mag aber durchaus Meinungen geben, die von meiner präskriptiven Ansicht abweichen.

Damit hätte sich auch die Frage nach dem Kasus geklärt: Die aufgezählten Wissenschaftler stehen im Dativ, weil *zwischen* den Dativ regiert.

Answer (score 2):

"diesen" und auch "zwischen" machen eine elegante Lösung m.E. unmöglich, wenn man mehr als nur die Namen nennen will (also auch die Berufe/Titel).

An Stelle einer Aufzählung (die ja gar keine ist - es ist offenbar ein Zweier-Treffen) würde ich einen Satz bilden nach dem Doppelpunkt:

> **Im** Buch geht es um **ein** Treffen zwischen zwei Wissenschaftlern: **Der** Physiker
>   Adolf R. und der Astronome Mujiko P. ***begegnen*** sich o.ä. ...

Angekündigt wird so ein Ereignis (das Zusammentreffen) und nicht eine im Dativ stehende Mini-Liste. Habe soeben realisiert, dass es wohl Fiktion ist, deshalb Präsens und "ein Treffen".  Und schon ist man mitten in der Geschichte.

"*Das Buch geht um das Treffen...*" ist voll das Sachbuch-Framing!

---

> Ich sehe: 1 Löwe.

Statt

> Ich sehe einen Löwen.

kann als "Katalogstil" sogar seinen Reiz haben. Hier hebt das Zahlwort "1" den Akkusativ auf.

Aber

> Ich sehe: einen Löwen.

ist so dazwischen. Dann eher in der Bedeutung: Ich begreife jetzt, dass es ein Löwe war:

> Ich sehe: Ein Löwe.

---

Und mit Komma:

> Ich verstehe, Löwen, und werden die uns gefährlich?
>
> Ich verstehe Löwen, und die werden uns noch gefährlich.

Comment: Wieso ist das keine Aufzählung? Weil es nur zwei sind? Das spielt doch keine Rolle.

Comment: "Ich habe: Äpfel und Birnen" ist "Ich habe Äpfel und Birnen". Oder halt CNN-Stil: "Habe: Äpfel, Birnen". Kann zu einer expliziten Liste forciert werden. Aber "Kann mich nicht entscheiden _zwischen_:  Äpfel, Birnen" ? Das ist keine richtige Liste.

Comment: "zwischen" verlangt ein "und". Weil "_Es gibt ein Problem zwischen mir_" nur begrenzt Sinn macht, ist "zwischen mir und dir" keine Aufzählung.

Comment: Zunächst einmal gehört in Ihrem Beispiel ja gar kein Doppelpunkt hin, weil es keine *Ankündigung* einer Aufzählung ist. Anders wäre das bei: „Ich habe *Folgendes:* Äpfel und Birnen.“ Zweitens heißt es *zwischen Äpfel**n** und Birnen* (Dativ). Und drittens verstehe ich Ihr Argument mit dem *und* nicht. Hier werden vier Personen aufgezählt: „Zwischen Anne, Tine, Otto und Horst gab es rege Diskussionen.“ Nun werden zwei Personen aufgezählt: „Zwischen Anne und Hort gab es rege Diskussionen.“

Comment: Sie könnten daraus eine Frage machen!